# Calculate 2-month rolling average for group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, moving-average

I'm trying to calculate a two-month rolling average of a player's 'score' using the below df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'player_id': [1098, 1098, 1098, 1098, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116],
              'date': ['2018-06-22', '2018-06-23', '2018-07-24', '2018-07-25', 
                      '2018-07-22', '2018-07-23', '2018-07-24', '2018-07-25',
                      '2018-08-22', '2018-08-23', '2018-08-24', '2018-08-25'],
              'score': [-2,1,2,3,-8,3,2,-3,-2,1,2,3]})
```

I'd want the averages to be grouped by the 'player_ID' column so that player 1098 would have averages of -2, -0.5, 0.33, and 1 for each row, respectively. If there's just one date in 2020, it'd just be that value. If there's a date in January and February of 2020, the January row would just be that value while the Feb row would be the average of those two.

Comment: will you demonstrate the output of the two month window using the existing data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can group by `'player_id'` and use `expanding().mean()` method on `'score'` column:

```
df['rolling mean'] = df.groupby('player_id')['score'].expanding().mean().round(2).droplevel(0)
```

**Edit:**

Given the new information in the comments, perhaps you want `rolling.mean` method. Added some rows to the dataframe from the OP to better show what's going on. For the DataFrame `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'player_id': [1098, 1098, 1098, 1098, 1098, 1098, 1098, 1098, 
                                 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116], 
                   'date': ['2018-06-22', '2018-06-23', '2018-07-24', '2018-07-25', 
                            '2019-06-22', '2019-06-25', '2019-07-25', '2020-06-22', 
                            '2018-07-22', '2018-07-23', '2018-07-24', '2018-07-25', 
                            '2018-08-22', '2018-08-23', '2018-08-24', '2018-08-25'], 
                   'score': [-2, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 6, 5, -8, 3, 2, -3, -2, 1, 2, 3]})
```

Here we find the rolling mean over 60 days for each `'player_id'`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['player_id','date'])
df['rolling_mean'] = df.set_index('date').groupby('player_id', sort=False)['score'].rolling('60D').mean().round(2).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
    player_id       date  score  rolling_mean
0        1098 2018-06-22     -2         -2.00
1        1098 2018-06-23      1         -0.50
2        1098 2018-07-24      2          0.33
3        1098 2018-07-25      3          1.00
6        1098 2019-06-22      7          7.00
7        1098 2019-06-25      8          7.50
5        1098 2019-07-25      6          7.00
4        1098 2020-06-22      5          5.00
8        1116 2018-07-22     -8         -8.00
9        1116 2018-07-23      3         -2.50
10       1116 2018-07-24      2         -1.00
11       1116 2018-07-25     -3         -1.50
12       1116 2018-08-22     -2         -1.60
13       1116 2018-08-23      1         -1.17
14       1116 2018-08-24      2         -0.71
15       1116 2018-08-25      3         -0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the most elegant, but here you go:

```
import pandas as pd
    
#DataFrame you provided
df = pd.DataFrame({'player_id': [1098, 1098, 1098, 1098, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116],
                  'date': ['2018-06-22', '2018-06-23', '2018-07-24', '2018-07-25', 
                          '2018-07-22', '2018-07-23', '2018-07-24', '2018-07-25',
                          '2018-08-22', '2018-08-23', '2018-08-24', '2018-08-25'],
                  'score': [-2,1,2,3,-8,3,2,-3,-2,1,2,3]})
    
    #As best practice, set date strings to date type
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    
    """
    Group by player and date, then add a rolling average with minimum level 1
    (meaning you can start rolling from the first row). The rolling function creates a series
    from your dataframe
    """
    rolling_average_series = df.groupby(by=['player_id','date']).rolling(1)['score'].mean()

#Reset series as dataframe with .to_frame then reset index so that player_id and date are still columns
df_grouped = rolling_average_series.to_frame().reset_index(level=['player_id','date'])
```

Apologies for the weird formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'player_id': [1098, 1098, 1098, 1098, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116, 1116],
              'date': ['2018-06-22', '2018-06-23', '2018-07-24', '2018-07-25', 
                      '2018-07-22', '2018-07-23', '2018-07-24', '2018-07-25',
                      '2018-08-22', '2018-08-23', '2018-08-24', '2018-08-25'],
              'score': [-2,1,2,3,-8,3,2,-3,-2,1,2,3]})

window=4
min_periods=3
cap=10

def get_month(date):
    return date.month

df=df.sort_values(by='date')
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['month']=df['date'].apply(get_month)
df['elapsed_days'] = (df['date']-df['date'].shift(1)).dt.days
df['accumulative_elapsed_days'] = df['elapsed_days'].cumsum()

df['rolling_mean'] = df['score'].rolling(window, min_periods).mean().round(2)
```

print(df[['date','score','month','elapsed_days','accum_elapsed_days','rolling_mean']])
df.set_index('date',inplace=True)

```
df[['score','rolling_mean']].plot()
plt.show()
```

output:

```
         date  score  month  elapsed_days  accum_elapsed_days  rolling_mean
0  2018-06-22     -2      6           NaN                 NaN           NaN
1  2018-06-23      1      6           1.0                 1.0           NaN
4  2018-07-22     -8      7          29.0                30.0         -3.00
5  2018-07-23      3      7           1.0                31.0         -1.50
2  2018-07-24      2      7           1.0                32.0         -0.50
6  2018-07-24      2      7           0.0                32.0         -0.25
3  2018-07-25      3      7           1.0                33.0          2.50
7  2018-07-25     -3      7           0.0                33.0          1.00
8  2018-08-22     -2      8          28.0                61.0          0.00
9  2018-08-23      1      8           1.0                62.0         -0.25
10 2018-08-24      2      8           1.0                63.0         -0.50
11 2018-08-25      3      8           1.0                64.0          1.00
```